# Input String is not being equated to String from a file

Tags: java, string, file, while-loop, path

I am a rookie and this program is about reading from a text files to find a name and I cant get through it.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter file to read");
    String file = scan.nextLine();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))) {
        System.out.println("Enter name to validate, no entry will close");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            String row = scanner.nextLine();
            if (name.equals(row)) {
                System.out.println("Entry Permitted");
            } else if (name.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Entry Denied");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

These are the Strings from the file :

```
Taylor Swift        
Kylie Jenner        
Kanye West      
Lionel Messi        
Ed Sheeran      
Cristiano Ronaldo   
Neymar
The Eagles      
Phil McGraw     
Saul "Canelo" Alvarez
```

Comment: One suggestion: the names scan and scanner are too close. I would have called the scanner for the file something like fileScanner. Though I would have used a FileReader instead.

Comment: Please up vote https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955777/4313726 and confirm it is the best solution ... many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer will work ... we can "stream" line the solution with modern Java features.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        System.out.println("Enter file of names to read ...\r");

        Set<String> names = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(scanner.nextLine()))
                .stream()
                .map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println("Enter a name to validate, or a blank entry to exit ...\r");

        String name;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            name = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("auf Wiedersehen");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Entry %s", names.contains(name) ? "Permitted" : "Denied"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is a good answer.  Is there any reason why somebody has downvoted this answer ?  It works!